# How to call methods in SL OOB application from Dot net library and vice-versa?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0

I have a SL 5.0 OOB application installed on my Machine, I have another program written in C# dot net, I wanted to make call's from dot net app to SL application and once data is processed  SL app call back the dot net app, any suggestion for me to getting started that will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- host a WCF service (Server) that holds & maintains session & their callback pointers for both silverlight and dotnet app.
- both applications connect to this wcf service on start up and register their respective callbacks
- then on the wcf service side write logic to route calls and results from Dotnet app to silverlight adn vice-versa.